# Concatenate two pandas dataframe with the same index but on different positions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like

```
id    value_right    color_right     value_left   color_left
1      asd           red              dfs         blue
2      dfs           blue             afd         green
3      ccd           yellow           asd         blue
4      hty           red              hrr         red
```

I need to get the left values below the right values, something like

```
id    value          color
1      asd           red        
1      dfs           blue
2      dfs           blue
2      afd           green
3      ccd           yellow
3      asd           blue
4      hty           red
4      hrr           red
```

I tried to split in two data frames and to interleave using the id, but I got only half of the data on it, using the mod of the value of the id. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a view of the desired left and right side dfs, then [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename) the columns and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) them and [`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort) on 'id' column:

```
In [205]:
left = df[['id','value_left','color_left']].rename(columns={'value_left':'value','color_left':'color'})
right = df[['id','value_right','color_right']].rename(columns={'value_right':'value','color_right':'color'})
merged = pd.concat([right,left]).sort('id')
merged

Out[205]:
   id value   color
0   1   asd     red
0   1   dfs    blue
1   2   dfs    blue
1   2   afd   green
2   3   ccd  yellow
2   3   asd    blue
3   4   hty     red
3   4   hrr     red
```

Comment: There is a slight problem: sometimes the second item will be on the first position, because the sort will put them in order by id, but not between them.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're saying, if you have a new problem then post a new question and show some code and desired output, thanks